# Access value from a string object - Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Not sure why I am not able to access the keys from a string object
data looks like this
I am getting this data from a python variable

```
const data = '{regression: {success: 7310, total: 14154, failed: 4665, unstable: 2104, aborted: 75}, stable: {success: 2699, total: 4252, failed: 462, unstable: 15, aborted: 1076}, patch: {success: 2824, total: 5494, failed: 2518, unstable: 39, aborted: 113}}'
```

I need to extract the keys regression, stable, patch and eventually the details of how many test cases were in success, total, failed etc.

Tried to change the string to object using `JSON.parse(data)` but it gives error as its not an object.

How can I extract the keys and value in this case

Comment: It's a string, not an object. And it's not valid JSON, hence why it cannot be parsed. Where is that coming from? The best way is to either have an object or produce valid JSON to parse.

Comment: this is coming from a python variable. I need to access the details to display it in a table.

Comment: Is there any way to convert this to object or parse the data to fetch the desired results

Comment: This is where JSON.parse works: `console.log(JSON.parse('{"a": {"b" : "c"}}'), "\ntype: ", typeof JSON.parse('{"a": {"b" : "c"}}'));`. And here, it gives error: `console.log(JSON.parse('{a: {b : c}}'), "\ntype: ", typeof JSON.parse('{a: {b : c}}'));`.

Comment: yes I am aware of this. but this is the data I am getting. IS there any workaround to fetch the desired output

Comment: Yes, fix your Python code to send out valid JSON.  If you use `json.dumps`, that will happen automatically.'

Comment: I know I am going to get lots of 'eval is evil' replies to this but if you trust the source of your python output, you could do `let obj = eval('(' + data + ')')`, then you can call properties as you wish.  `obj.regression` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy approach to make this work.

In your Python code, use the `json.dumps()` method to convert a Python dictionary into valid JSON, like below.

```py
import json

dictonary = {
  "name": "Name",
  "age": 0
};

print(json.dumps(dictionary)) # Returns JSON
```

Then, in your JavaScript, add the following code.

```js
const data = "{\"name\": \"Name\", \"age\": 0}";
console.log(JSON.parse(data)); // Returns a JavaScript object
```

The JavaScript code should now return a JavaScript object without any errors.